# Plural or Singular after "no"

Tags: american-english, word-usage

After searching product on website, should I show one of these?

`There is no any product`

or

`There is no any products`

?

Some people on Internet said that singular is used after uncountable noun and plural after countable one but I don't agree with that. I think singular should be used after "no".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's Too Basic. It's not appropriate on a site designed for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Both are ungrammatical. _No_ does not occur in construction with _any_; the determiner phrase is _not any_. Also, the verb has to agree with _product(s)_, since this sentence has been _There_-inserted. So if it's plural, the verb should be _are_, not _is_. So don't show either of them. By the way, are you **sure** that everybody coming to your website understands what you mean by "product(s)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plural.  We use singular when there is exactly 1.

But your sentence is wrong, because you have used two determiners (*no* and *any*) to qualify one noun. I suggest:

> No matching products found.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct, but either "no products match your search" or "no product matches your search" would be a good replacement.